# Debugger to step out from not responding function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have code in C# that reads from a socket.
For some reason the other side doesn't respond.
I'm stuck with the debugger on `NetworkStream.Read` method.
If I break the debugger I'm still stuck there.
I want to establish again the connection without terminating the whole program.
How can I tell the debugger to skip out of `Read`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking if data is available when doing the read?  The example [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx) looks like this:

```
do
{
    numberOfBytesRead = myNetworkStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    // other stuff
}
while(myNetworkStream.DataAvailable);
```

I imagine this *should* skip if there's no data available.  Though I have little experience with `NetworkStream` so perhaps the problem you're facing would happen regardless.

If that's the case then it sounds like you want to make it a non-blocking call so the application can continue even if the stream is blocked.  (This is probably a good idea for a number of reasons.)  So reading from the stream in another thread would be the way to go.  How you go about doing that very much depends on the version of .NET you're using.

Comment: The server got my request for the bytes but for some reason it raised an exception inside and went out of the listener. Outside it was catched so he is waiting for other connections now but the client is stuck at this Read.